# PHP DOMDocument double DOCTYPE

Tags: php, domdocument

I got an situation with PHP DOMdocument.

I got a HTML file with an double doctype and i think therefor php can't reach the `<head>` element with `$doc->getElementsByTagName('head');` (Length is returning 0).

So how can i remove the first DOCTYPE within the DOCdocument.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <Some html code>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing between `<head></head>`

Comment: Thats not the point. This is an example. Fill some in in the head code.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your QUESTION**

You can do this by using `array_slice()` to remove the first line

e.g

```
$html = file_get_contents('index.html');
$html = implode("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $html), 1));
```

**To clarify your problem**

The `<head>` tag IS empty.

**To retrieve the contents within head**

```
preg_match('/<head>(.*)<\/head>/s', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: No this is not the type off solution i looking for. There are 1 miljoen other documents that go through this methode. I realy need an solution with PHP DOMDocument. And the head is not empty. This is an example code.

Comment: Updated my answer for you that with something that will retrieve the contents of the head tag for you without needing DOMDocument